# Mock equation of state

Tags: astrophysics, terminology, neutron-stars

I am student of astrophysic i need to meaning of ["mock equation of state"](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=mock+equation+of+state).
And is there any specific way to generate mock equation of state.

Answer (score 4):

I guess that what is meant is a relationship between the pressure of the gas and it's density, temperature and composition.

No, there is no specific way to make something that you have defined in a completely general way, without describing any context - is this a star, a compact object, the interior of a star forming cloud, an ionised nebula?

A mock equation of state for a neutron star might be 
$$P = A\rho^{\alpha},$$
where $P$ is pressure, $\rho$ is density and $A$ and $\alpha$ are constants of your choosing to reflect you chosen physics. You might even have several different $A,\rho$ value in different density intervals to cope with changes in the equation of state and composition that are made such that $P$ vs $\rho$ forms a continuous relationship.

For example, an ideal degenerate gas of electrons (accompanied by ions, say in a white dwarf) obeys $P \propto \rho^{5/3}$ at low densities, but become $P \propto \rho^{4/3}$ at higher densites. Then when neutronisation takes place the gas pressure again becomes dominated by non-relativistic neutrons with $P \propto \rho^{5/3}$, but if a neutron gas become relativistic then $P \propto \rho$.  Alternatively you might adjust the value of $\alpha$ to reflect a (non-ideal) hardening of the equation of state due to nucleon repulsion at high densities by allowing $\alpha \rightarrow 2$.

Comment: i always inspire from your interpretration.Mr Rob could you please tell me in TOV equations of hydrostatic equilibirium.would  the equation for gravitational potential v(r) satisfy (0)=0 for interior of star? also do you have some graph of gravitational potential v(r) for the interior of neutron star.if have then please give me